# Logrotate Fails Without Error

Tags: logrotate

Ok, I made a boo-boo. *I think*

**Problem:**
Logrotate fails (or I incorrectly think its dead) and does not provide any error message to explain why:

```
● logrotate.service - Rotate log files
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/logrotate.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Fri 2021-12-31 13:05:25 CST; 42min ago
     Docs: man:logrotate(8)
           man:logrotate.conf(5)
  Process: 27844 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 27844 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Dec 31 13:05:25 server1.example.com systemd[1]: Starting Rotate log files...
Dec 31 13:05:25 server1.example.com systemd[1]: logrotate.service: Succeeded.
Dec 31 13:05:25 server1.example.com systemd[1]: Started Rotate log files.
```

I wanted to automatically restart logrotate using systemd because sometimes it would fail after a reboot.  Therefore in my `/usr/lib/systemd/system/logrotate.service` file I added:

`Restart=always`

The above addition kill logrotate service.  From there I decided to undo my dirty work and by deleting `Restart=always` and `systemctl daemon-reload && systemctl start logrotate`

No luck.

Then I decided to investigate the syslog and see if I could find any clues, using:
`#grep "logrotate" /var/log/syslog`.  This yielded a clue:

```
Dec 31 00:00:03 server1 systemd[1]: logrotate.service: Succeeded.
Dec 31 00:36:16 server1 clamd[3544]: Fri Dec 31 00:36:16 2021 -> ^File path check failure on: /var/tmp/systemd-private-2f8e6be5a16040adb29706b9e31ae841-logrotate.service-DbrlAK
Dec 31 00:37:31 server1 systemd[1]: logrotate.service: Succeeded.
Dec 31 12:51:17 server1 systemd[1]: logrotate.service: Succeeded.
Dec 31 13:00:58 server1 systemd[1]: logrotate.service: Succeeded.
Dec 31 13:05:25 server1 systemd[1]: logrotate.service: Succeeded.
```

Note: all the times where you see "Succeeded" are from me manually trying to start logrotate.

I read in [this post on server fault](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1320383/failed-to-start-rotate-log-files) that this can problem can be caused by logrotate trying to access logs outside of the `var/log/` directory.  And I though that this may be my problem, however I can't find any indicator of a log outside `/var/log`, except for the syslog error above:

reiteration:

```
Dec 31 00:36:16 server1 clamd[3544]: Fri Dec 31 00:36:16 2021 -> ^File path check failure on: /var/tmp/systemd-private-2f8e6be5a16040adb29706b9e31ae841-logrotate.service-DbrlAK
```

From I investigated clamd, but

```
#grep "log" /etc/clamav/clamd.conf 
LogSyslog false
LogFile /var/log/clamav/clamav.log
```

Yields, nothing.  Does anyone know why logrotate won't start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`logrotate.service` is supposed to be inactive. It doesn't run as a daemon but is triggered periodically by `logrotate.timer`, check `systemctl status logrotate.timer`.

Comment: Ok... I was wondering about that... but prior to my editing logrotate.service it would always show as active....  It just appeared as if I had broken something.  In any case, I also check logrotate.timer and it was/is working.  so I guess accidentally repaired logrotate somehow..  Thanks for your feedback. Much appreciated... on to other bugs :-) Happy New Year!